# toggle hide javascript function

Tags: javascript, button, toggle

I have a div with two divs inside that I want div A to show, with the other hidden. by default I want div A to show

```
<div id="0">
  <div id="A">this is A</div>
  <div id="B">this is B</div>
</div>

<div id="1">
  <button1>this is 1</button>
  <button2>this is 2</button>
</div>
```

Separate to this is the buttons to action it.

Here is where I got with the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
$('.toggle').hide();
$('a.togglelink').click(function() {
    $('.toggle').hide();
    $(this).parent().next('.toggle').toggle();
    return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: your HTML doesn't match the JS please provide us with matching code...

Comment: as abc123 said, show us the actual code, not formatted. We don't know which elements contain the .toggle class or whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/VbLWP/)

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <div id="divA" class="toggle">this is A</div>
  <div id="divB" class="toggle">this is B</div>
</div>

<div>
  <button value="divA">this is 1</button>
  <button value="divB">this is 2</button>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
showHideDivs("divA");

$("button").on("click", function(){
    showHideDivs(this.value)
});

function showHideDivs(id){
    $(".toggle").hide();
    $("#" + id).show();
}
```

**Edit**: @ShowcaseImagery - I realized that this question was asked specifically for `bootstrap` and that my solution is more of a JS/jQuery implementation. If you need similar functionality and you're using `bootstrap` you should look into the [collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) accordions. The [collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) documentation should outline how to do this correctly.

Comment: @ShowcaseImagery - Glad to hear it =) Good luck

Comment: @ShowcaseImagery - I added an edit to my answer after realizing that you needed a bootstrap approach. Hope it's helpful =)

Answer (score 0):

div0 and div1 is not valid XHTML. I'm guessing that's where your problem is. Instead use the id tag like so:

```
<div id="div0">YOUR STUFF HERE</div>
<div id="div1">MORE STUFF HERE</div>
```

Comment: I suppose thats common knowledge and the OP meant it as clarification.

Comment: Perhaps, but considering how many college students post here with their homework, I'm not confident.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. However, it is a valid comment.  Why not point out that `<button1>` and `<button2>` aren't valid HTML either.  Also just changing what you specified changes nothing on functionality of the above code.  The user needs to post his real HTML or specify what he meant.

Comment: I hear what you're saying, but after reading OP's post, I think you're giving him/her too much credit.

If you go through my answers over the last few days, you'll see that I've had to drop to the most basic level multiple times and been marked correct where the OP just didn't know what they're doing while every other answer was deep and complex.

So if I'm right, then my answer DOES answer the question. And if I'm wrong, and they are on a higher level of actually writing functional code and they are just stuck, then someone else's answer (like your own) will rise to the top.

Comment: josh, promise its not homework lol. thanks for my corner larssy

just for the record
<div id="div1">this is div</div? everyone happy now :)

Comment: @ShowcaseImagery please update the original question so that we can answer it appropriately.